# Session id to the Solr url

Tags: java, solr, solrj, jsessionid

I am trying to send a query to a server running Solr as follows:

```
String solrServerUrl = //SomeBaseUrl
CommonsHttpSolrServer searchServer = new CommonsHttpSolrServer("http://"+solrServerUrl);
QueryResponse result = searchServer.query(query,SolrRequest.METHOD.POST);
```

In the query request that I send over to the Solr server,I append the sessionId string as follows(for logging purposes):

```
String solrServerUrl = SomeBaseUrl.concat("?sessionId");
```

When I run the server, I get the following exception:

> nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid base url for
>   solrj.  The base URL must not contain parameters

Can somebody point out how I can forward the unique session-id to the Solr server so that the session-id is picked by the tomcat valves set up in the destination Solr-server for logging purposes?

Thanks

Comment: Not quite an answer, but an observation. You are adding parameters to the URL on a POST, not a GET. Is the valve going to look at a URL parameter on a POST?

Comment: @rfreak - I was under the impression that the Tomcat valves should be able to process any kind of request. GET/POST should not be an issue. I may be wrong though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible that way with the actual `CommonsHttpSolrServer` code, it doesn't matter if you're using POST or GET (even if rfeak's comment looks good).

There's a condition like this in the main `CommonsHttpSolrServer` constructor:

```
if( _baseURL.indexOf( '?' ) >=0 ) {
    throw new RuntimeException( "Invalid base url for solrj.  The base URL must not contain parameters: "+_baseURL );
}
```

I would try using the `SolrQuery#setParam` method. This way you might be able to add additional request parameters, which should just be ignored by the Solr request handler.

Comment: I realized passing the parameters in the CommonsHttpSolrServer's constructor is not the way to go. Is there a methodology for the request to be crafted so that the sessionId is embedded in the url?

Comment: I had a look at the `SolrServer` and `CommonsHttpSolrServer` classes, but I haven't found a quick way to achieve what you want. Maybe you can try using the SolrQuery#setParam but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks. I will try setting the params to the Query, see if that works.

Comment: Setting the params in the Query seemed to have passed the session over to the Solr server. I was wondering if this would have an bearing on the search results in the longer run?

Comment: Great it works! I updated my answer with all this discussion we've had. I guess that additional parameter should just be ignored by the Solr request handler.